# Aggregate column containing different values into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a table like so:

```
    type          load             total
    -------------------------------------
Default           base             26.2
Default           peak             29.625
NonDefault        base             26
NonDefault        peak             29.4
```

I'm currently attempting to sum the total column `Sum(total)` and group by the load, which leaves the type column needing to be aggregated.

Most of the time type is the same (all `Default`) so I can simply add this to the grouping, however sometimes it isn't (as in the example).  I want to be able to aggregate this column so that if both types are showing (`Default` and `NonDefault`) then I want the aggregate to output `Default` for all columns, which will allow me to carry on with the grouping.

I realise this may be a job for a custom function?  Or are there any better ideas of how to condense this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(type) as type,
       load,
       sum(total) as total
from T
group by load
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/192a8/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
       sum(total), 
       min(type) 
from table 
group by load
```